# Why are Daenerys' hands injured when she gazes on the dragon eggs?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Season 1, Episode 2, of *Game of Thrones*, about midway through, Daenerys is looking at her eggs while two handmaidens attend to her and they are applying an ointment to her hands which have bloody abrasions on them. There is no explanation for why she has these wounds. Is this from a scene that was cut out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's from the wounds that Daenerys got on her hands from riding her horse. Earlier in the episode, because of her wounds, Jorah had to carry her down from her horse and her handmaidens help her up. They notice the wounds on her hands.

> **One of the handmaidens**: Khaleesi. Your hands.

Screencap:
[image: screencap of above scene]

Notice how Daenerys is keeping her palms open and how her handmaidens are holding Daenerys' arm.

> Later, her handmaidens tend to all the small wounds she's collected while riding and tell her the various legends they've heard of dragons.

- [The Kingsroad — HBO](https://www.hbo.com/game-of-thrones/season-1/2-the-kingsroad)

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't notice that.